# Find all the coordinates on a path

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid, maze

Given a 2D string as input, either as a string with newlines or a list of lines, output the coordinates `(x, y)` of all the hashes (`#`) in the list.  The input will only contain hashes and spaces. (and newlines, if you choose to take input as a 2D string)

If there are no hashes, you can output anything.

Output should be unambiguous as to which numbers are paired with which.

Example:

```
##
```

Should output:

```
(0,0), (1,0)
```

That assumes 0-based indexing, starting from the top left. You may start from any corner, use 0 or 1-based indexing, and/or output `y` first. (e.g. in the form `y,x`).

More test cases (again, all using 0-based top-left `(x, y)` indexing):

```
    #
#####
#

(4, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (0, 2)


# ###
### #

(0, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1)
```

Note that these test cases all list by rows, not by following the path.

You may assume the hashes will form a continuous trail, i.e. `# #` will never be the input. (probably won't matter, but in case somebody wants to regex this)

You also can output the coordinates in any order you want, i.e. vertical columns, horizontal rows, or just an unsorted list.

Comment: Can we assume the input only contains hashes and spaces?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem yes, editing that into the question.

Comment: Would [this](https://tio.run/nexus/grime#@1@QmBCj/P@/srICl4KyMgA "Grime – TIO Nexus") or [this](https://tio.run/nexus/grime#@1@QWJwQo/z/v7KyApeCsjIA "Grime – TIO Nexus") be valid output formats?

Comment: @Zgarb basically with the extra 1,1 and the hash? Eh, sure.

Comment: Would [my alternate format](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105654/42545) be valid?

Comment: @FlipTack define flat list? i.e. [1, 2, 3, 4] where [1,2] and [3,4] are the coordinates? No.

Comment: What about `[[(0, 0)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(2, 3)]]` - a list for each row, containing its coordinates?

Comment: @FlipTack that works, yes.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Would [this.. "format"](https://i.gyazo.com/d85a93315d8527bd45a16ae325bf0c21.png) qualify as input?

Comment: @devRicher that test case won't happen at all, but I may allow that input format. I'll ping you in chat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Slip](https://github.com/Sp3000/Slip), 2 + 1 = 3 bytes

+1 byte for the `p` flag. Code:

```
`#
```

Explanation:

The `p`-flag returns the position of each occurence of the following:

```
`#      // The character '#'
```

[Try it here!](https://slip-online.herokuapp.com/?code=%60%23&input=%23%20%23%23%23%0A%23%23%23%20%23&config=p)

Comment: I think we have a winner

Comment: Any explanation?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk The backtick escapes a single character as string. The flag requests positional results.

Comment: @Adám oh, cool!

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>7 6</s> 5 bytes

This is using 1-based indexing with `(1,1)` in the top left corner.

```
oo&fh
```

Explanation:

```
o        % convert char to double 
 o       % remainder mod 2 ('#' == 35, ' '==32) makes spaces falsy
  &f     % apply `find` with 2d-output 
    h   % concatenate outputs to display x- and y-coordinates side by side
```

Thanks @DJMcMayhem and @LuisMendo for each -1 byte!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@fr5aW8f9/tLoCECirW6srgwCIBgmoxwIA)

Comment: You could do `ooH#fh` to save one byte. (convert to integers, mod2) Since space is even (mod 2 == 0, falsy) and `#` is odd (mod 1 == 1, truthy)

Comment: Oh, great, thank you very much!=)

Answer (score 8):

### [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 5 bytes

```
pa`\#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/grime#@1@QmBCj/P@/srICl4KyMgA)
The output format is a bit funky, but OP has stated that it's valid.

### Explanation

Grime is my 2D pattern matching language.
The part after `` ` `` is the *pattern*, in this case a 1×1 square containing a `#`-character.
Grime will search the input grid for a match, and prints the first one it finds by default.
The part before `` ` `` contains options, in this case signifying that all matches (`a`) should be printed, along with their positions and sizes (`p`).

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

This is actually just a golf of my [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41430965/7089349) on a similar topic.

```py
lambda a,e=enumerate:[[(i,j)for j,B in e(A)if'!'<B]for i,A in e(a)]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JczBCsIwEATQu18xpofuQr5A7KH9jZDDihvY0sYSUn8/Rp3LwBuYljBhk/3xFIjXSfO5a5GqtxDI/MrpVbD6BZahNLOl8Trel/hl8/OfhWOT/qNv2cjycVZivhzFcqXUV27BARichxt6ft3BxQ8)

The loops through the 2D list, recording the hash characters, and returns the result. We save a byte by using `char > '!'` rather than `char == '#'`, because the input will only consist of hashes and spaces, and so hashes (`0x23`) will be the only characters larger than exclamation marks (`0x21`).

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>70</s> 67 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c>' '?[i%l,i/-l|0]+' ':'',l=~s.indexOf`
`)
```

Outputs a newline-and-space-separated list of coordinates, e.g.

```
4,0
0,1 1,1 2,1 3,1 4,1
0,2
```

You can get much shorter with a weird output format:

```
s=>s.replace(/#/g,(c,i)=>[i%l,i/-l|0]+c,l=~s.indexOf`
`)
```

This outputs

```
    4,0#
0,1#1,1#2,1#3,1#4,1#
0,2#
```

for the second test case. It's still clear which numbers are paired with which...

Answer (score 5):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
$#:'#'I.@:=,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloKJspa6s7qnnYGWr878EJGKsYKKgoqCurKwARApApKCszpWanJGvoO6ZV1BaAuWUQMX8S0sQgmkKJf8B)

### Explanation

```
$#:'#'I.@:=,  Input is y.
           ,  Flatten y
   '#'    =   and form bit vector of equality with #.
      I.@:    Compute positions of 1s
 #:           and convert each to base
$             shape of y.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM) 16.0, 5 chars = 9 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) or 6 chars = 8 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Gives list of (y,x) pairs from top left.

```apl
⍸⎕='#'
```

`⍸` where

`⎕` input

`=` equals

`'#'` this character*

* It is possible to save a character at the cost of one byte by replacing `'#'` with `⍕#` (format the root namespace)

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=i%u2190%7B%28%2C%u2375%29/%2C%u2373%u2374%u2375%7D%20%u22C4%20%u22A2%u2206%u21903%205%u2374%27%20%20%20%20%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%27%20%u22C4%20i%20%u2206%3D%27%23%27%20%u22C4%20%u22A2%u2206%u21902%205%u2374%27%23%20%23%23%23%23%23%27%20%u22C4%20i%20%u2206%3D%27%23%27&run) Note that `⍸` has been emulated with `i`  because TryAPL runs version 14.0.

Comment: Pretty sure in Dyalog APL encoding 1 char = 1 byte, no?

Comment: @devRicher Normally, but `⍸` is not included in the single byte version. See the "bytes" link.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
n⁶T€,€"J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5/3qHFbyKOmNTpArOT1////aCUFIFBW0lFSBgEQDRJQigUA)

Given a 2D array of characters (= a list of strings):

```
            Implicit input (example):
               [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#']
               ,['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
               ,['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
n⁶          Not-equal to space (⁶).
               [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
               ,[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
               ,[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
  T€        Indices of 1s in each row
               [[5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1]]
    ,€"J    Pair each, vectorizing, with y-indices
               [[[5,1]], [[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2]], [[1,3]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 61 bytes

```
s=>[for(c of(x=0,y=1,s))if(c<' '?(y++,x=0):(x++,c>' '))[y,x]]
```

Returns 1-based coordinates. Easily switchable between `[y, x]` and `[x, y]` ordering. Ungolfed:

```
function coords(s) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 1;
    for (Var c of s) {
        if (c == "\n") {
            y++;
            x=0;
        } else {
            x++;
        }
        if (c == "#") {
            console.log(y, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 37 bytes

```
:%s/#/\=line('.').','.col('.').' '/g<cr>
```

Since V is mostly backwards compatible, you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2@lWqyvrB9jm5OZl6qhrqeuqaeuo66XnJ8D5Sio66dz/f@vrKCsrMwFxArKAA)

A straightforward regex solution, where it replaces each '#' with the location it was found in (one-based indexing). I was a little bit worried while writing this that the location would change after substituting the first one on a line, but that doesn't seem to be an issue. TBH I'm pleasantly shocked by how simple this solution ended up being.

Unfortunately, vimscript is very verbose, so most of the bytes come from separating the results so that is still legible. Otherwise, we could do

```
:%s/#/\=line('.').col('.')/g
```

But this creates output that's pretty hard to interpret. Additionally, it will only work it the grid is always 9x9 or smaller.

This is a really fun solution because it shows each pair of coordinates *at the location* of the hash it represents. For example, the input

```
# ###
### #
```

outputs

```
1,1  1,3 1,4 1,5 
2,1 2,2 2,3  2,5
```

Of course, if we were using V, we could remove the trailing newline, and compress the regex. Then it could simply be

```
Í#/½line('.').','.col('.').' '/g
```

(32 bytes)

But since this is the exact same approach and still painfully verbose, it doesn't seem worth it to use a golfing language.

Comment: Okay, the whole "shows each pair of coordinates at the location of the hash" is pretty darn cool. +1

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 53 bytes

```
concat.zipWith(\y l->[(x,y)|(x,'#')<-zip[0..]l])[0..]
```

Input is taken as a list of strings. The output is a list of `(x,y)` pairs (0 indexed), e.g.

```
*Main> concat.zipWith(\y l->[(x,y)|(x,'#')<-zip[0..]l])[0..] $ ["# ###","### #"]
[(0,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(4,1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, 141 bytes

```
w=io.read()x=w:sub(1,w:find("\n")-1):len()_,c=w:gsub("\n","")for i=0,x do for j=0,c+1 do if w:sub(c*x+i,c*x+i)=="#"then print(i,j)end end end
```

It's 2:30 AM, I'm in bed, on my phone. Why am I doing this?

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 2 bytes

```apl
⍸<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HvDpv/aY/aJjzq7XvU1XxovfGjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz@D/QNo5Uj0lLa9YnSsls7hAIU0BKATUYqhg9Kh3i7oymrCxgilIWAEIlCEAxERTZARRpAxVoqCsDgA)

I win. (Though it's technically tie because we don't count flags in bytes anymore...)

Basically works like [the existing APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105664/78410), but it doesn't test for equality with `'#'`; it tests if each char is non-blank.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, <s>80</s> 68 bytes

```
{y=0;it.each{it.eachWithIndex{x,i->print(x=='#'?"($i,$y)":"")};y++}}
```

Example input:

```
[#   #,#   #,#####]
```

Example Output:

```
(0,0)(4,0)(0,1)(4,1)(0,2)(1,2)(2,2)(3,2)(4,2)
```

Comment: Why split the input into lines, when the task description allows taking an already split list of lines?

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
Position@"#"
```

Operator form of [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html). Assumes a 2D array of characters. 1-indexed starting at the top left entry. Outputs a list of coordinates in the form `{row,column}`.

Comment: The way I read the task description, I don't think taking a 2D array of characters is allowed for languages that support strings.

Comment: @smls http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2216/61980

Comment: I'm not convinced. For one thing, that question focuses on `char[]`, which is actually a common way to store strings in C-based languages. Also, this task description specifically mentions "either as a string with newlines or a list of lines", and doesn't mention list-of-lists-of-characters or 2D matrix of characters.

Comment: @smls Exactly. The consensus was that if a question specifies a string, it means a sequence of characters, and if your language has more than one way of expressing that, then you are free to choose the one that suits your golfing needs. Specifying "either as a string with newlines or a list of lines" does nothing to change that since if you represent each line as an array of characters then you get exactly a 2D array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 69 bytes

```
for(;$a=$argv[++$i];)for($j=0;""<$c=$a[$j++];)echo$c>" "?"$j $i,":"";
```

Uses 1-based indexing starting from the top left.
Use like:

```
php -r 'for(;$a=$argv[++$i];)for($j=0;""<$c=$a[$j++];)if($c>" ")echo"$j $i,";' '    #' '#####' '#    '
```

Will output:

```
5 1,1 2,2 2,3 2,4 2,5 2,1 3,
```

Answer (score 1):

### RBX.Lua, 131 bytes

Has to assume input is valid (Z is the flat axis, whitespaces are `White` tiles, hashes can be any other color, top-left part is located at `0, 0, 0`) and all parts are part of the same model `M`, and the model is otherwise empty.

```
for k,v in pairs(workspace.M:GetChildren())do if v.BrickColor~=BrickColor.new("White")then print(v.Position.X,-v.Position.Y)end end
```

Sample input/output:

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you provide a valid i/o example?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk There, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 113 bytes

```c
i,j,k,l;f(char**p){i=strlen(*p);l=strlen(p);for(j=0;j<l;j++)for(k=0;k<i;k++)if(p[j][k]==35)printf("%d,%d ",k,j);}
```

Outputs from test cases:

```
0,0 2,0 3,0 4,0 0,1 1,1 2,1 4,1 
4,0 0,1 1,1 2,1 3,1 4,1 0,2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#NY07DoMwEET7nALZQvKCi0CUavFJEAUKseJPwDKkQpydrEPYat7OSG830konPWrxePWxKAKsRs1L9M9REKA/gbKeorDqirbxaMsSEjti1xh0xEaL0NqudZ1StzuEaMZFC5YPMh8yRhoLuO3v3owC1p8uVG2n1gvjGeecSQqcItvwaOujzejO9j9LL5qRsAIMn2UWjEHCOim@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 25 bytes (22 characters)

```perl6
{^∞ZX@_».indices("#")}
```

Takes input as a list of lines.
Outputs one list per line, each containing (y, x) tuples for the coordinates.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS1Ow/V8d96hjXlSEQ/yh3XqZeSmZyanFGkrKSpq1/4sTKxXSFFTiFdLyixRUbNMy8zKLM/SSM/JzC/SKC3IySzSUYvJi8pQ0gaZBZbmUlbm4FIBAGcgCAi4gl0tZAcxSBtL/AQ)

#### How it works

```perl6
{                    }  # A lambda.
{    @_»             }  # For each input line:
        .indices("#")   #    get x-coordinates.  (4) (0 1 2 3 4) (0)
 ^∞                     # Range from 0 to Inf.    0   1           2 ...
   Z                    # Zip with:              (0 (4)) (1 (0 1 2 3 4)) (2 (0))
    X                   #    Cartesian product.  ((0 4)) ((1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4)) ((2 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 + 1 = 25 bytes

+1 byte for `-n` flag. Coordinates are 1-based, one number per line.

```ruby
gsub(/#/){p$`.size+1,$.}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P724NElDX1lfs7pAJUGvOLMqVdtQR0Wv9v9/ZQVlZWUuIFZQ/pdfUJKZn1f8XzcPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 4 bytes

```
⊚=@#
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oqaPUAjCgpGIFsiIyMiXQoKRiBbIiAgICAjIgogICAiIyMjIyMiCiAgICIjICAgICJdCg==)

```
⊚=@#
 =@#  # mask of hash characters
⊚     # coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 80 bytes

```c
x,y;f(char*s){for(x=y=0;*s;printf(*s-35?"":"%d,%d ",x,y),*s++==10?++y,x=0:++x);}
```

Requires input as newline-delimited char array, prints output to screen.

Ungolfed & usage:

```c
x,y;

f(char*s){
 for(
  x = y = 0;             //init coordinates
  *s;                //iterate until end
  printf(*s-35 ? "" : "%d,%d ", x, y),     //print coordinates or empty string
  *s++==10 ? ++y, x=0 : ++x              //advance to the right or the next line
 );
}


main(){
 f("    #\n#####\n#    ");
 puts("");
 f("# ###\n### #");
}
```

Comment: 78 bytes: `x,y;f(char*s){for(x=y=0;*s;*s++==10?++y,x=0:++x)*s==35&&printf("%d,%d ",x,y);}`