# Match coordinates with their values

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid, maze

Given 3 input items, a list of coordinate pairs, a 2D string, and a single-character string, output whether the character at each coordinate of the 2D string is equal to the single character.  You can take the input in any order and the coordinates may be 1-indexed.

You may take the 2D string as a 2D list, a list of lines, or a 2D string.

Example: `(0,0), "#_\n__", "#" -> True`

The string is

```
#_
__
```

The char at the coordinate `(0,0)` (from the top left) is `#`.  This is equal to the third input item, `#`, so you output `True` (or any truthy value)

Example: `[(0,0), (1,1)], "#_\n_#", "#" -> True`

The string is

```
#_
_#
```

The characters at the coordinates of `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` are both `#`, so the output is true.

The output is only true iff every coordinate matches a hash.  Not every hash has to have a matching coordinate though.  If there are no occurrences of the single char (`#` in some of the test cases) in the 2D string, the output is still just falsy.

You can assume the coordinates will always be within the bounds of the 2D string.

More test cases: (I put the single char second for ease of readability)

```
[(0,0), (2,1), (3,0)], #

#_##
#_##

True


[(0,0), (1,1), (3,0)], #

#_##
#_##

False (1,1 is not a hash)



[(1,1)], a

#a##
#a##

True


[(4, 0), (3, 0), (2, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 3)], ' '


 ####
 #   
   # 

True
```

Note the last test case uses spaces as the single char string, and hashes around the spaces.

[Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105649/find-all-the-coordinates-on-a-path) (inverse of this challenge)

Comment: Can we assume that input is a 2d array instead of using "\n"?

Comment: @rahnema1 not a 2D array, but an array/list of lines yes.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk I believe this falls into the category [Cumbersome I/O formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/60043)

Comment: In your first example coordinates are in the format `(row, column)`  but in the  last example coordinates are in the format `(column, row)` .

Comment: @JungHwanMin no, because it trivializes the challenge a bit more.

Comment: @rahnema1 ah, thanks for catching that. For reference, you may use either coordinate input method.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Some languages treat strings like an array of chars. Wouldn't that make this challenge trivial already?

Comment: Can the coordinates be 1-indexed?

Comment: @KritixiLithos yes, they can.

Comment: @JungHwanMin yeah, it would. I don't want to trivialize it any more though.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk my point is that there is no difference between allowing 2D arrays and not allowing it because there is no distinction in some languages.

Comment: @JungHwanMin eh, I guess I'll allow it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the "list of coordinate pairs" can be understood as a 2×N matrix, where N is the number of coordinates. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Luis yes that's correct

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Thanks for clarifying. Also, can we assume the list / matrix will not be empty?

Comment: @Luis yeah, sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com/download-zone.htm), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Prompts for list of coordinate pairs (row,column), then 2D array, then character.

```apl
∧/⎕=⎕[⎕]
```

`[⎕]` prompt for coordinates and use them to scatter pick from

`⎕` prompted input (2D array)

`=` compare the selected elements to

`⎕` input (the character)

`∧/` check if all are true (AND-reduction)

**Test cases** (`⎕IO←0` to match examples, but this is not necessary):

[First example](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%28i%u2190%u22820%200%29%28%u2282a%u21902%202%u2374%27%23___%27%29%28%u2282%2Cc%u2190%27%23%27%29%20%u22C4%20%u2227/c%3Da%5Bi%5D&run)

[Second example](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%28i%u2190%280%200%29%281%202%29%280%203%29%29%28%u2282a%u21902%204%u2374%27%23_%23%23%27%29%28%u2282%2Cc%u2190%27%23%27%29%20%u22C4%20%u2227/c%3Da%5Bi%5D&run)

[Third example](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%28i%u2190%280%200%29%281%201%29%280%203%29%29%28%u2282a%u21902%204%u2374%27%23_%23%23%27%29%28%u2282%2Cc%u2190%27%23%27%29%20%u22C4%20%u2227/c%3Da%5Bi%5D&run)

[Fourth example](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%28i%u2190%u2282%281%201%29%29%28%u2282a%u21902%204%u2374%27%23a%23%23%27%29%28%u2282%2Cc%u2190%27a%27%29%20%u22C4%20%u2227/c%3Da%5Bi%5D&run)

[Fifth example](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%28i%u2190%281%200%29%20%282%200%29%20%283%200%29%20%283%201%29%20%283%202%29%20%282%202%29%20%282%203%29%20%282%204%29%20%283%204%29%29%28%u2282a%u21904%205%u2374%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%23%23%23%20%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%27%29%28%u2282%2Cc%u2190%27%20%27%29%20%u22C4%20%u2227/c%3Da%5Bi%5D&run)

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 39 bytes

Takes the inputs:

1. `a` list of `(x, y)` integer coordinates
2. `b` list of strings
3. `c` single character string

---

```
lambda a,b,c:{b[y][x]for x,y in a}=={c}
```

Comment: On this site, you don't need to name your functions. You can remove the `f=`. Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first answer!

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, <s>45</s> <s>38</s> 29 bytes

```
@(A,B,C)A(1+B*[rows(A);1])==C
```

A function that takes a 2D array of chars as `A` and coordinates(0 based) `B` as a two column matrix of `[col row]` and the matching character as `C`.
The two element coordinates(using matrix multiplication) converted to linear index.

Note: Previous answer that made use of sparse matrix was wrong.

Other Contributors:

[Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin) for saving 5 bytes noting  that [0 1 0] can be regarded as false value!!

[Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) for saving 2 bytes that `~0 == true` and notification about sparse matrix.

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/#yzA84)

Comment: Nice :) You can skip `all` and save three bytes. `1 1 1` is true, and `1 0 1` is false in Octave, so it should be OK. :)

Comment: Great approach! I like how this exploits the fact that logical indices [need not have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2462898/2586922) the same size as the indexed array

Comment: In addition to Stewie's suggestion, you can replace `true` by `~0` to save 2 bytes

Comment: @StewieGriffin  Thanks it is really OK:)

Comment: @LuisMendo Good point

Comment: @LuisMendo It was my mistake for assuming that input format is [row col], so I flipped B in tio to work correctly, Thanks for notification

Comment: @LuisMendo my answer based on sparse matrix was wrong (since it is not always correct to index a matrix with logical matrix of smaller dimensions! ) and consumed more bytes so I changed it

Comment: Oh now I see the problem with the smaller logical mask. It linearizes

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

Takes the inputs:

1. `a` array of `[x, y]` integer coordinates
2. `s` array of strings
3. `c` single character string

---

```
(a,s,c)=>a.every(([x,y])=>s[y][x]==c)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
#3~Extract~#~MatchQ~{#2...}&
```

1-indexed. Due to how arrays are structured in Mathematica, the input coordinates must be reversed (i.e. `(row, column)`)

**Usage**

```
#3~Extract~#~MatchQ~{#2...}&[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}}, "#", {{"#", "_", "#", "#"}, {"#", "_", "#", "#"}}]
```

> `True`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
->\c,\h,\n{all map {n eq h[.[0];.[1]]},c}
```

```
->$_,\h,\n{all .map:{n eq h[.[0];.[1]]}}
```

Expects the 2D string as a 2D list.

*Thanks to b2gills for -1 byte.*

Comment: If you used `$_` instead of `\c` you could use `.map:{…}` saving one byte

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills: Oh, I didn't realize the space was optional in `.map: {…}`. That's useful to know. Also, it's a shame that prefix `||` isn't implemented yet, it could make the inner lambda simply `n eq h[||$_]`...

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 27 bytes

```
s!c=all(\(x,y)->s!!y!!x==c)
```

Usage example: `( ["#_##","#_##"] ! '#' ) [(0,0), (2,1), (3,0)]` -> `True`.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>80</s> 77 bytes

Saved 3 bytes, thanks to pinkfloydx33

```
a=>b=>c=>{foreach(var i in a){if(b[i[0]][i[1]]!=c){return 1<0;}}return 1>0;};
```

a is the pairs of coordinate, b is the list of lines, and c is the single-character string.

Comment: You can replace `false` with `1<0` and `true` with `1>0` and save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ịṪ⁸ịḢð€Q⁼⁵
```

This only works as a full program. Input order is indices, string array, singleton string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/fDnaseNe4AMXYsOrzhUdOawEeNex41bv3//3@0homOoaaOgoahjhGIMtYx0Yz9H62emJScqq7DpaCempaeAWZkZmXngBm5eakF6rH/1VPVAQ)

#### How it works

```
ịṪ⁸ịḢð€Q⁼⁵  Main link.
            Left argument:  P (array of coordinate pairs)
            Right argument: S (array of strings)
            Third argument: C (singleton string)

     ð€     Combine the links to the left into a dyadic chain and call it with each
            p = (x, y) in P as left argument and S as the right one.
ị             Unindex; retrieve the strings of S at indices x and y.
 Ṫ            Tail; yield s, the string of S at index y.
  ⁸ị          Unindex; retrieve the characters of s at indices x and y.
    Ḣ         Head; yield the character of s at index x.
       Q    Unique; deduplicate the resulting string/array of characters.
        ⁼⁵  Compare the result with the third argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>72</s> 63 bytes

```
c [] _ _ =1<2;c ((f,s):t) m n |n/=lines m!!s!!f=1>2|1>0=c t m n
```

Input of
`c [(0,0), (1,0), (3,0)]  "#_##\n#_##" '#'`
Outputs
`False`

Input `c [(4, 0), (3, 0), (2, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 3)]  "     \n ####\n #   \n   # " ' '`

Output
`True`

UnGolfed

```
checkfunc :: [(Int,Int)] -> String -> Char -> Bool
checkfunc [] _ _ = True
checkfunc (x:xs) string char | char /= ((lines string)!!(snd x))!!(fst x)= False  -- Checks first coordinates and returns False if no match
                             | otherwise = checkfunc xs string char --Otherwise iterate over remaining coordinate pairs
```

Comment: There is still unnecessary whitespace left: `c[]_ _=1<2;c((f,s):t)m n|n/=lines m!!s!!f=1>2|1>0=c t m n`

Comment: Also as you are doing boolean logic, the implicit conditional `if n/=lines m!!s!!f then False else c t m n` can be replaced by `n/=lines m!!s!!f&&c t m n`.

Comment: Finally, as the OP says `You may take the 2D string as a 2D list, a list of lines, or a 2D string.` you can drop the `lines` and directly take a list of lines as input.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 68 bytes

```
def f(l:(Int,Int)*)(s:String*)(c:Char)=l forall{x=>s(x._2)(x._1)==c}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 39 bytes

```
#(apply = %3(map(fn[[x y]]((%2 y)x))%))
```

Example (string input is a vec of vec of characters):

```
(def f #(apply = %3(map(fn[[x y]]((%2 y)x))%)))
(f [[0 0] [1 1] [3 0]] (mapv vec ["#_##" "#_##"]) \#)
```